# Deleting an array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If `BOOK_COPY_ID` and `id` are both equal at 0th index, my whole array is becoming empty. If I put return, it is also getting deleted.

This is my code:

```
var i = 0;
    while(i < bookLoop.length)
    {
        if(parseInt(bookLoop[i].BOOK_COPY_ID) == parseInt(id))
        {
           bookLoop.splice(i);           
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: do `splice(i, 1)`, you also have to specify how many items to splice, otherwise it will just to them all until the end of the array

Comment: Please explain your goal in more detail

Comment: A better way to do this is using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `deleteCount` argument for [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Without that, it deletes all elements past the index:

```
bookLoop.splice(i, 1);
```

You also shouldn't increment `i` when you splice, because you removed the index:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < bookLoop.length)
{
    if(parseInt(bookLoop[i].BOOK_COPY_ID) == parseInt(id))
    {
        bookLoop.splice(i);           
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

If you don't specify the 2nd argument `deleteCount` it will delete all the items from the current position to the end of the array.

So, your code should be something like this:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < bookLoop.length)
{
    if(parseInt(bookLoop[i].BOOK_COPY_ID) == parseInt(id))
    {
       bookLoop.splice(i, 1);           
    } else {

        i++;
    }
}
```

Another nice way is one of the ones mentioned in this post: https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/

```
var newArray = bookLoop.filter(function(value){

    return parseInt(value.BOOK_COPY_ID) == parseInt(id);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to add the second parameter (deleteCount)

> If deleteCount is omitted, or if its value is equal to or larger than
>   array.length - start (that is, if it is equal to or greater than the
>   number of elements left in the array, starting at start), then all the
>   elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted.

Read more about [array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var id = "123";

var bookLoop = [
  { BOOK_COPY_ID: "123" },
  { BOOK_COPY_ID: "456" },
  { BOOK_COPY_ID: "789" }
];

var i = 0;

while (i < bookLoop.length) {
  if (parseInt(bookLoop[i].BOOK_COPY_ID) == parseInt(id)) {
    bookLoop.splice(i, 1);
  } else { i++; }
}
console.log(bookLoop);
```